# minecraft server query not echoing motd

Tags: php, minecraft

I downloaded the code from here: https://github.com/FunnyItsElmo/PHP-Minecraft-Server-Status-Query

I want to echo out the server's MOTD, with this code:

```
<?php

include_once 'get.php'; //include the class
$status = new MinecraftServerStatus(); // call the class

$response = $status->getStatus('localhost'); // call the function

$statusTxt = "offline";
$version ="N/A";
$ping ="N/A";
$players = "0/0";
$host = "N/A";
$motd = "N/A";
$version= "N/A";

if($response){
    $statusTxt="online";
    $players = $response['players'] . "/" . $response['maxplayers'];
    $version = $response['version'];
    $ping = $response['ping'];
    $host = $response['hostname'];
    $motd = $response['motd'];
    $version = $response['version'];
}

?>
<div id="banner">
<div id="status"><?php
echo$statusTxt;
?></div>
<div id="version"><?php
echo$version;
?></div>
<div id="ping"><?php
echo$ping;
?></div>
<div id="players"><?php
echo$players; 
?></div>
<div id="host"><?php
echo $host; 
?></div>
<div id="motd"><?php
echo $motd; echo $version;
?></div>
</div>
```

but that returns:

```
online
103
3/100
localhost
1.7.5
```

how do I echo out the MOTD of the server?

Comment: Does your MOTD have any odd chars or colour codes?

Comment: Try changing your MOTD to be simple and then see if it works. I don't see any other reason why this wouldn't show.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend just using Auto Bukkit instead, it is very simple for minecraft servers and the MOTD works 100% of the time.